# Excel Date Format Change through text formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been trying to change the Excel date `31/03/2020` to `=TEXT(D4,"MM-DD-YYYY")` but its not working is there any other way to do this by Excel Formula.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is D4 text or a date? What happens if you change formatting of D4 to number?

Comment: It is text when i use this formula =TEXT(DATEVALUE(D4),"dd/mm/yyyy") an error is appear that is #VALUE!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use LEFT, MID and RIGHT.

```
=MID(D4,4,2)&"-"&LEFT(D4,2)&"-"&RIGHT(D4,4)
```

Comment: I have updated the result which has / i do not know why.

Comment: Sorry.. it should be `mid(D4,4,2)`